# Python pseudo inverse and determinant of a vector

Tags: python, vector, numpy, pandas, linear-algebra

How to compute the pseudo inverse of a vector and also the determinant? (preferably with either numpy, or better pandas)

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
import numpy
vect = [1, 2, 3, 4]
numpy.linalg.pinv(vect)
```

But I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-e362654e383f> in <module>()
     19 vect = [1, 2, 3, 4]
---> 20 print(np.linalg.pinv(vect))

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.pyc in pinv(a, rcond)
   1544     _assertNonEmpty(a)
   1545     a = a.conjugate()
-> 1546     u, s, vt = svd(a, 0)
   1547     m = u.shape[0]
   1548     n = vt.shape[1]

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.pyc in svd(a, full_matrices, compute_uv)
   1269     """
   1270     a, wrap = _makearray(a)
-> 1271     _assertRank2(a)
   1272     _assertNonEmpty(a)
   1273     m, n = a.shape

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.pyc in _assertRank2(*arrays)
    153         if len(a.shape) != 2:
    154             raise LinAlgError, '%d-dimensional array given. Array must be \
--> 155             two-dimensional' % len(a.shape)
    156 
    157 def _assertSquareness(*arrays):

LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be             two-dimensional
```

Comment: The error clearly suggests the problem "LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be  two-dimensional"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you want this?

```
>>> np.linalg.pinv([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
array([[ 0.03333333],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.1       ],
       [ 0.13333333]])
```

Note the extra set of brackets.  As the error message suggests, you can only take the pseudo-inverse of a matrix.  If you just have a vector you need to make it into a 1-row matrix.

Comment: Thank's for the tip! Indeed it works for linalg.pinv, but it does not for linalg.det! (error: "Array must be square") Do you have any idea how I can deal with det?

Comment: @user1121352: Can I ask what use case you have for a determinant of a non-square matrix?

Comment: @user1121352: The determinant is only mathematically defined for square matrices.

Comment: No it's okay, I was adapting a code I did in the past with Octave, and the Octave's diag() function both can return a vector from a matrix, or a matrix from a vector (highly confusing!). Thank's for the tip, I keep it in my books.

Comment: @BrenBarn: there are actually some generalizations you can make and still call something a determinant, but they're pretty obscure, and seldom useful.  (BTW, your avatar takes me way back..)